# Issue to align 2 DIVs under each other

Tags: html, css

would you know why my 2 DIVS (news & article) are not aligned under each other except when I reduce the size of the browser window? Normally would expect them to be aligne on the right side of the screen (float:right) under each other but the "article" DIV looks left-aligned.Here is the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Grek/45rdH/embedded/result/
Thanks

```
<div class="menu">
      <div class="inner"> <a href="www.dfdsfdsfs.com/index.html" class="logo">Gregory</a>
    <ul>
          <li > <a href="www.dfdsfdsfs.com">Category 1</a> </li>
          <li > <a href="www.dfdsfdsfs.com">Category 2</a> </li>
          <li > <a href="www.dfdsfdsfs.com">Category 3</a> </li>
          <li > <a href="www.dfdsfdsfs.com">Category 4</a> </li>
          <li > <a href="www.dfdsfdsfs.com">Category 5</a> </li>
          <li class="selected"> <a href="www.dfdsfdsfs.com/">Category 6</a> </li>
          <li > <a href="www.dfdsfdsfs.com">Contact</a> <span class="pipe"></span> </li>
        </ul>
    <div class="social">
          <div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.123.com" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="450" data-show-faces="false"></div>
        </div>
  </div>
    </div>
<div id="quote">
      <blockquote>
    <p>"Nos soutenons depuis la début"</p>
    <cite>Innovation</cite> </blockquote>
      <blockquote>
    <p>"L'eau est d'une qualité exceptionnelle"</p>
    <cite>Hydro-geologiste</cite> </blockquote>
    </div>

<div class="news">
<p>test news</p>
</div>
<div class="article content">
      <h1>Biography</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    <a class="image-popup-vertical-fit" href="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8241/8589392310_7b6127e243_b.jpg" title="Caption. Can be aligned it to any side.">
    <img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8241/8589392310_7b6127e243_s.jpg" width="75" height="75">
</a><h2>Sub-title</h2><p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?</p>
    <p><strong>LOREM IPSUM</strong></p>
          <h3>Tel. +123 456.789 - E-mail: contact@kjhhklh.com</h3>
  </div>


    </div>

<div class="footer">
      <p class="left">contact@mydomain.com | + 12 345.678.910</p>
      <p class="right">contact@mydomain.com | + 12 345.678.910</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
/* Reset
/* -------------------------------------------- */

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary, time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
b, strong {
    font-weight: bold;
}
em {
    font-style: italic;
}
/* Font family reference
/* -------------------------------------------- */

/*

font-family:'FuturaW01-LightOblique';
font-family:'Futura W01 Book';
font-family:'Futura W01 Book Oblique';
font-family:'Futura W01 Medium';
font-family:'Futura W01 Heavy';
font-family:'Futura W01 Bold';

*/


/* Global
/* -------------------------------------------- */

html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    min-width:950px;

}
body {
    height: auto;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Futura W01 Book', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.285714286; /* 18px */
    color: #2b2b2b;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    z-index: 10;
    position: absolute;
    background: url(../images/biographie.jpg);
    top: 0;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
a {
    outline: none;
    color: #2b2b2b;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.menu li a, .footer li a {
    font-family: 'Futura W01 Heavy', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 10px;
    line-height: 1;
    letter-spacing: 0.10em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ecb825;
}
.menu li a:hover, .menu li.selected a {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}
/* Fade border under links on hover */
.csstransitions .menu a, .csstransitions .footer a {
    -webkit-transition: border, color 0.2s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: border, color 0.2s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: border, color 0.2s ease-out;
    -o-transition: border, color 0.2s ease-out;
    transition: border, color 0.2s ease-out;
}
p a {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ECB825;
}
p a:hover {
    border-bottom-color: #fff;
}
h1, h2 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
h1 {
    font-family: 'Futura W01 Heavy', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    letter-spacing: 0.04em;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    padding-top:5px;
}
h2 {
    font-family: 'Futura W01 Heavy', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    letter-spacing: 0.04em;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    padding-top:5px;
}
h3 {
    font-family: 'Futura W01 Heavy', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-top: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}
p {
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-bottom: 1.25em;
}
strong, b {
    font-family: 'Futura W01 Heavy', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
}
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    border: 0;
    -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
}
/* Navigation
/* -------------------------------------------- */
.menu {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 768px;
    max-width: 1950px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 65px;
    z-index: 310;
    color: #2b2b2b;
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image: url('../images/shadow-menu.png');
    background-position: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}
.menu .inner {
    height: 65px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #fff;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
}
.menu .logo {
    position: absolute;
    left: 81px;
    top: 19px;
}
.menu ul {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 18px auto 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    padding-right: 200px;
}
.menu li {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 30px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.menu li:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
}
.menu li a {
    float: left;
}
.menu .pipe {
    width: 1px;
    float: left;
    height: 33px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    position: relative;
    top: -10px;
    background: url('../images/pipe.gif') 100% 0 repeat-y;
}
/* Search */
.social {
    position: absolute;
    right: 61px;
    top: 23px;
    text-align: right;
}

/*News box xml driven */

.news {
    float: right;
    width: 450px;
    height: 20px;
    margin-right:75px;  
    position: relative;
    z-index: 15;
    margin-top: 90px;
    background: #ccc;
    /* max-width: 25%; */

    overflow-y: scroll!important;
}

/* Article - white bg */
.twocolumns {
    -moz-column-count: 2; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-column-count: 2; /* Safari and Chrome */
    column-count: 2;
}
.article {
    float: right;
    text-align:justify;
    width: 450px;
    height: 450px;
    padding: 60px 32px 49px 82px;
    margin-right:75px;  
    position: relative;
    z-index: 15;
    margin-top: 120px;
    background: #eee;
    /* max-width: 25%; */

    overflow-y: scroll!important;
}

.article p {
    padding-right:20px;
}
.article h1, .article h2 {
    margin-top: -4px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
}
/* Article - no bg, large text */
.article-full {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 84px 0 49px 0;
    background: none;
    max-width: 100% !important;
}
.article-full p {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 60px;
    line-height: 56px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: 'Futura W01 Light', Arial, sans-serif;
    margin: 0 82px;
}
.article-full p strong {
    font-family: 'Futura W01 Heavy', Arial, sans-serif;
}
/* Footer
/* -------------------------------------------- */
.footer {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 300;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 768px;
    max-width: 1950px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #2b2b2b;
}
.footer a {
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-bottom-color: #2b2b2b;
}
.footer a:hover {
    border-bottom-color: #ECB825;
}
.footer p.left {
    margin: 10px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    color: #fff;
    padding-left: 20px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-family: 'Futura W01 Heavy', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 10px;
    line-height: 1;
    letter-spacing: 0.10em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding-bottom: 1px;
}
.footer p.right {
    margin: 10px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    padding-right: 20px;
    color: #fff;
    padding-left: 20px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-family: 'Futura W01 Heavy', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 10px;
    line-height: 1;
    letter-spacing: 0.10em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding-bottom: 1px;
}
/* Quovolver Demo Styles */

/*
 |  All required styles for the effect
 |  are labeled with this *required*
*/

#quote {
    left: 2%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 335px;
    z-index: 2;
}
blockquote p {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    text-align: right;
    font-family: 'Futura W01 Book', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    /* color:  #0A4672; */
    color: #fff;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #333;
}
blockquote cite {
    font-family: 'Futura W01 Book', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: block;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    color: #FFF;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #333;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    text-align: right;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    margin-top: -5px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
/*
 |  Setting the width for the blockquotes is required
 |  to accurately adjust it's contianer
*/

blockquote {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 430px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
/*
 |  The #quote_wrap div is created
 |  by Quovolver to wrap the quotes
*/

#quote_wrap {
    margin: 40px 0;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set `clear: right;` on the `.article` div.

```
.article
{
  clear: right;
}
```

This basically means (quoted from [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_clear.asp)):

> No floating elements allowed on the right side

That should fix your problem, as setting `clear: right;` on `.article` will ensure that the earlier div can't be floating on the right side of it. Now the `.article` div will be forced to sit under it instead, even when there is actually enough space for it to float next to it (which is the reason why it floats next to it).

Here's a fixed up <kbd>[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/45rdH/1/embedded/result/)</kbd> result.